# Rails 4 Devise Omniauth with multiple providers tied to model associated with user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have a question on how to approach the design of an integration. I have two models `Company` and `User`. In my case, users will register for my app and then be presented with the option to connect the app to their different accounts (Twitter, Facebook, and LinkedIn) so that they can view/create posts/tweets/etc. Because `Company` `has_many` `Users` and the social media accounts belong to the company, I want to tie the credentials to the `Company` model using another model called `Provider` to store the credentials, therefore allowing any user that has permission to access the company's social media account.

I've been following various tutorials on how to configure multiple omniauth providers, but they all focus on tying them to the user model and tell me to add `devise :omniauthable` to my user model.

How do I make `Company` omniauthable instead of the user? Do I even need to make my model omniauthable if I'm not going to allow user authentication/registration view omniauth?

This is my first time building social media integrations, so I hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thought, I came up with an approach that works quite well and is much simpler than what I was originally attempting. It seems like a hack, so I'm certainly open to see if anyone has a cleaner approach.

The first thing I did was to give up on making the company model omniauthable, as I didn't want users to log in as a company, but rather as a user of a company. Instead, I made the user model omniauthable and then created an `Identity` model, which `belongs_to` the user and the company. `User` and `Company` both `has_one` `Identity`. Once a user authorizes a provider, a new identity is created.

Because both the user and the company own the identity, other users that `belong_to` the company can access that identity through the company. Likewise, if a user logs in and does not have any identities, the system will check if their company has any identities before allowing them to add one. This way, there is only ever one identity per provider per company, and it doesn't matter which user creates it.

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar to this working. We have an app that allows uses omniauth and devise to allow oauth identification from FB, LI and Twitter. I keep the Devise and Omniauth tied to the User model and have an Identity model that has a provider field, a uuid and a user_id relation. This way using the email returned from the provider or the active session I can determine whether the user already exists in the system and link the Identity accordingly. With Twitter is a little tricky because they don't return an email so you have to add to determine whether the user has a verified email and if they don't you need to prompt them for one. You can definitely do the same thing by making the Company model omniauthable and devise_authentcatable but it seems a little counterintuitive. I use the standard user approach and have the user own one or more companies. Hope this helps.